# Rollup Angular2 class error (InjectMetadata)

Tags: angular, typescript, rollupjs

I'm using the standard tsc (v1.8.10) to compile and Rollup.js (v0.34.3) to bundle an Angular 2 app but when executed the following error appears:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor InjectMetadata cannot be invoked without 'new'(…)
```

the rest of the stack trace seems to go through the dependency injector:

```
decoratorInvocations.map.decoratorInvocation    @   app.js:4012
convertTsickleDecoratorIntoMetadata @   app.js:4007
ctorParameters.map  @   app.js:3911
parameters  @   app.js:3911
parameters  @   app.js:4092
_dependenciesFor    @   app.js:4531
resolveReflectiveFactory    @   app.js:4430
resolveReflectiveProvider   @   app.js:4453
resolveReflectiveProviders  @   app.js:4460
resolve @   app.js:4930
resolveAndCreate    @   app.js:4959
bootstrap   @   app.js:31991
(anonymous function)    @   app.js:32032 <= call to bootstrap
(anonymous function)    @   app.js:32036 <= iife invocation
```

I'm quite new to Angular2, specifically.